# How to run multiple Micro services on same port?

Tags: spring-boot, https, microservices, port

We have org restrictions on usage of multiple ports to be exposed globally.
An application hosted on EC2 using one webapp (Angular + Node JS ) and 7 Spring Boot applications/services (JARs). so here since each service is hosted with different port, total 8 ports were exposed globally.

Now, due to the restriction on ports usage, I need to expose only one port (https port 443). Since the web app is using the other services running on different ports, I want to find a way to either run all the services on same port or a way to redirect (both listen and respond) all ports to 443.

Please suggest what is the best approach for this.

Best Regards,
Prashant

Comment: ApiGateway may be a good solution for you. You should have only apigateway exposed to outside. Then based on incoming url you can direct calls to corresponding service.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ApiGateways.

Read more on Nginx website: [Building microservices using an api gateway](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway)